# Updating ratings array displays duplicated value in the state

Tags: angular, redux, state

I want to **update** the **ratings( which is an array of numbers)** of my **sister object** by **pushing new rating value to the ratings array**. The update actually works but without reloading the page I see twice the sent value, which is coming from the **state**. 
So I assume the problem is in the way of updating the array in the state, in the **reducer** or in the way I am receiving the **result** in my epic function.

my rate-sitter.ts:

```
rateSitter(filledStars) {
    let rating = filledStars;
    let sitter: Sitter = this.sitter as Sitter;
    this.usersActions.rateSitter(sitter, rating)
  }
```

my users.actions.ts:

```
  rateSitter(sitter: Sitter, rating: number): void {
        console.log(sitter);
        console.log(rating);
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({
            type: UsersActions.RATE_SITTER,
            payload: { sitter, rating }
        });
    }
```

my users.epic.ts:

```
   rateSitter = (action$: ActionsObservable<any>) => {
        return action$.ofType(UsersActions.RATE_SITTER) // Listen for this action
            .mergeMap(({ payload }) => { // payload: (subject: Subject, date: Date): When this action is activated, call ws through service class or directly like below
                return this.usersService.rateSitter(payload.sitter, payload.rating)
                    .map((result) => ({ // when web service responds with success, call this action with payload that came back from webservice
                        type: UsersActions.RATED_SITTER,
                        payload: payload // Hack: Db contains all data, not just yours.
                    }))
                    .catch(error => Observable.of({ // when web service responds with failure, call this action with payload that came back from webservice
                        type: UsersActions.FAILED_RATED_SITTER,
                        payload: error
                    }));
            });
    }
```

my users.reducer.ts:

```
case UsersActions.RATE_SITTER:
        return state;
    case UsersActions.RATED_SITTER: 
        let indexSitter = state.sitters.findIndex(sitter => { return sitter._id === action.payload.sitter._id });
        let newRatings = [...state.sitters[indexSitter].rating, action.payload.rating];
        console.log(newRatings);
        console.log(indexSitter);
        let newSitterObj = Object.assign({}, state.sitters[indexSitter]);
        newSitterObj.rating = newRatings;

        let newSitters = [...state.sitters.slice(0, indexSitter),
            newSitterObj,
        ...state.sitters.slice(indexSitter + 1)];
        console.log(newSitters);
        console.log(action.payload)
        return tassign(state, { sitters: newSitters });
    case UsersActions.FAILED_RATED_SITTER:
        return state;
```

and finally my users.service.ts

```
  rateSitter(sitter: Sitter, rating: number) {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                //'Authorization': 'my-auth-token' // If you use auth.
            })
        };
        sitter.rating.push(rating)
        return this.http.put("http://angular2api2.azurewebsites.net/api/internships/" + sitter._id, sitter, { responseType: 'text' });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because you're modifying your state within user.service.ts.

By calling `sitter.rating.push`, you're adding the rating into your state by mutating it. Within your reducer, you're then adding it a second time, even though it's already been added

You should avoid mutating the state if possible.

In the service, you can instead of `sitter.rating.push` do something like:

```
let copy = { ...sitter, rating: [...sitter.rating, rating]}
return this.http.put("http://angular2api2.azurewebsites.net/api/internships/" + copy._id, copy, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Which will create a copy of `sitter`, and add the rating to the copy instead.

Comment: thank's for your point. I thought users.service is only responsible for the http request, and the reducer is the one that handles the state.  but then I was wrong. By removing   `sitter.rating.push(rating)` it works cause sitter already contains the rating value I guess.

Comment: It should be, absolutely. However, because `sitter` is held in memory, when you mutate it, you're also changing anywhere else that holds the same reference to `sitter`. This is why mutating state is generally a bad idea

Comment: If you remove `sitter.rating.push(rating)` it may not work, no. If you did that without implementing the change above, it would not be included in the HTTP request, and the rating may be lost when you refresh

Comment: oh no you were right, just when I thought I totally get it.

Comment: is there another way of simplifying it from the start maybe so I can prevent needing to make a copy of my sitter. I feel like it gets a bit complicated this way and there must be a simpler solution?

Comment: It may not be the simplest, but it's arguably the most correct. One of the points of redux style architectures is that state is not modified

Comment: yeah i see that, I meant that probably my design is not  good from the start, and if I could improve something in e.g my users.action or user.reducer then I wouldn't have do this ? ..this is what I meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169527/discussion-between-user184994-and-codehip).